# Issue in adapters android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, getview

I have response where i am getting in adapters and displaying in textview but problem is it prints the item two times in listview. I checked the response. It also have only one item. But when I checked in debug mode, the loop prints in adapter two times. I couldn't find solution for this. For eg: in a list if it has 10 items.(A,B,C etc.,) it displays as 20 items (A,A,B,B,C,C etc.,)Please help me.

```
 public class ListAdaptersTest extends BaseAdapter  {
ArrayList<Persons> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;
ImageLoader loader;
 Persons movie;
  Activity activity;
  public static final String NAME="name";
    public static final String image="image";
    ArrayList<Persons> data=new ArrayList<Persons>();


public ListAdaptersTest(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Persons> movies) {
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    data=movies;
    activity=context;

      loader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    try{
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
     movie = null;
        movie = data.get(position);
        final   String name=movie.getName();
        holder.tvName.setText(name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

}

[image]

When I check the response, it's displaying as

```
E/REsponse(4989):     Response{"id":27136,"cast_id":3,"order":0,"credit_id":"52fe4e769251416c7515736b","profile_path":"\/rrN6d7WR.jpg","name":"Katharine Isabelle","character":"Tamara"}
```

10-29 02:01:56.934: E/Final(4989): Finaltrue
 E/REsponse(4989): Response{"id":21320,"cast_id":4,"order":1,"credit_id":"52fe4e769251416c7515736f","profile_path":"/d9YmZ.jpg","name":"Danielle Harris","character":"Amy"}
 E/Final(4989): Finaltrue
 E/REsponse(4989): Response{"id":27775,"cast_id":5,"order":2,"credit_id":"52fe4e769251416c75157373","profile_path":"/gNeWQz9oqF.jpg","name":"Chelan Simmons","character":"Kayla"}
 E/Final(4989): Finaltrue
10-29 02:01:56.937: E/REsponse(4989): Response{"id":61903,"cast_id":6,"order":3,"credit_id":"53da2fb40e0a2652f000200d","profile_path":"/jMUbn5I63NDlqM650.jpg","name":"Glenn Thomas Jacobs","character":"Jacob Goodnight"}
10-29 02:01:56.937: E/Final(4989): Finaltrue

Comment: loop? what loop are you talking about?

Comment: when i checked in debug mode, it repeats the item two times and execute next item. @pskink you can check screenshot

Comment: Log.d data size in getCount() and data.get(position) in getItem()

Comment: are you sure your data doesn't contain duplicates?

Comment: yes i checked the response @pskink

Comment: check it in your adapter, in getCount() and getItem()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to know that I think that your problem caused by two reasons first  you should use array adapter    not    base adapter , second  you should see us how you call the adapter and the creation of the persons list in your activity.

Comment: yes you are right. when i used array adapter, it's working. why so? may i know the reason?

Comment: Cause all override methods called back by super constructor

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out this line of code, in your public View getView method

```
if (v == null) {
```

This can be the source of the problem due to recycling issues.